# Read RSS on Windows Phone 7 and Pass data to next Page

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

On Windows Phone 7:

I want to read RSS feed with 3 different field: Title, Description-1, and Description-2. But I want to show only title and description-1 in main page as listbox.

When user click on each item then it goes to next page which just show title and description-2 field related to the item user clicked on it.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

passing data to a "subpage" is handled with the NavigationService class. As an example, you can do something like this, to push your rssdata to the page you want to show the information!

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Format("/MySubpage.xaml?param={0}", rssdata), UriKind.Relative));
```

In your subpage  in the OnNavigatedTo() method you can read the data and work with it.

Hope this helps.